# PHP form validation preventing empty form submitting

Tags: php, validation

I have created a simple form with login session capabiltites, i am using mysqli_connect_errno()  and  added a condition

```
     if ($_POST['username']=="") {

     $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) .    '/form.html';
     header('Location: ' . $home_url);
     $Err = "Invalid value";
       }
```

and

```
     <label for="username">Name </label><br>
     <input type="text" name="username"class="text">
     <span class="red"><?php echo $Err;?></span>
```

but the error message is not showing up  on   empty submit

Comment: because you are redirection to some page in your condition. Next line will never get execute

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned `header('Location:'.$home_url);` then how could you see the error. Pass the error message in header location

replace your code to

```
$Err = "Invalid value";
header('Location: ' . $home_url.'?err='.$Err);
```

and print the error like this

```
if(isset($_GET['err']))
{          
    echo $_GET['err'];         
}
```

Comment: its not visible if i write it before redirecting

Comment: @Ezhil did you see he is redirecting to html page. PHP code will not work. OP has to change it to `.php` file

Comment: i think thats the problem will check on it.

Comment: Using Javascript should work for now. i am a beginner in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
header('location:' .$home_url?flag=y);
```

the above line is be be written in php page

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['flag']) && $_REQUEST['flag'] == 'y'){ echo "valid";} else{ echo "Invalid"; } ?>
```

the above code is to be written in html page

Answer (score -1):

If you write this way

```
if ($_POST['username']=="") {

     $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) .    '/form.html';
     header('Location: ' . $home_url);
     $Err = "Invalid value";
       }
```

What will happen your page get redirected from header() function and code below that will never execute. This is something dangling code. so instead of that you need to write as follow

```
if ($_POST['username']=="") {

     $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) .    '/form.html';
$Err = "Invalid value";     
header('Location: ' . $home_url);

       }
```

Comment: its not visible if i write it before redirecting